# Laravel implode function on images array

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, implode

How can I make this an implode function using array of images? I am getting an error of:

> implode(): Invalid arguments passed

My controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'promotion_image' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->has('promotion_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload

        $promotion = [];
        foreach ($request->file('promotion_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/promotion_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($promotion, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($promotion);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

    foreach ($promotion as $key => $value) {
        $promotionImage = new Promotion;
        $promotionImage->promotion_image = implode(' , ',$value);
        $promotionImage->save();
    }
    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('success', 'Image Inserted');
}
```

My view:

```
 @foreach($promotions as $promotion)
           <tr>  

      //HERE IS WHERE THE IMAGE ARE VIEWED      <th><img src="{{ asset('storage/promotion_images/' . $promotion->promotion_image) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></th>
            <th><a href="/admin/airlineplus/promotions/{{ $promotion->id  }}/edit" class="fa fa-edit btn btn-primary btn-lg"></a></th>

         </tr> 
         @endforeach
```

Comment: To have it working you should be sure `$value` is actually an array since `implode()` function only accepts array as second argument. Put first line in foreach block `dd($value);` to check what type of variable is that.

Comment: sir, can you edit the code please ? :( im trying hard since last night cant even get the right code.

Comment: but what I want on my code is to insert the images in one column in my database thats why it has an implode function

Comment: I am telling you where to start with debugging given error. Again, in first line in second foreach loop put `var_dump($value); exit;` or shorter `dd($value)` and tell what has been got - what is `$value` actually. It should be an array to get rid of implode error message.

Comment: it shows a text .."Desert_01.jpg" after dd($value)

Comment: How can I store them i ONE ROW now?

Comment: Look, I need to store them in ONE ROW .. I need to insert them in one row which are my images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, try without foreach loop

```
if (count($promotion)) {
    $implodedPromotion = implode(' , ', $promotion);
    $promotionImage = new Promotion;
    $promotionImage->promotion_image = $implodedPromotion;
    $promotionImage->save();

    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('success', 'Image Inserted');
}

return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');
```

*Supplemental*:

If you have that value in your view and want to show those images, you should do the next:

```
@foreach($promotions as $promotion)
    @php
        $imagesImploded = $promotion->promotion_image;
        $imagesExploded = explode(',', $imagesImploded);
    @endphp
    <tr>
        @foreach($imagesExploded as $image)  
        <th><img src="{{ asset('storage/promotion_images/' . trim($image)) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></th>
        @endforeach
        <th><a href="/admin/airlineplus/promotions/{{ $promotion->id  }}/edit" class="fa fa-edit btn btn-primary btn-lg"></a></th>
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: sir all is working now but my last problem is I cannot show the images in my view pls help for the last time to finish my project

Comment: Sir @Tpojka , I edit the code above added the VIEW. there you will see how i view my images. please see and help me for the last time for me to marked your answer as solved